# merge Object and array mapping object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Merge one object into array object basis on object key and array object key mapped

````
{
'id':49,
'city':'bangalore',
'country':'India'
}
arr=[{
{title: 'Location ID', field: 'id', width: 200, _width: 200, filter: 'text'},
{title: 'City', field: 'city', width: 200, _width: 200, filter: 'dropdown'},
{title: 'Country', field: 'country', width: 200, _width: 200, filter: 'dropdown'}
}]

expected results:
[{
{'id':49,title: 'Location ID', field: 'id', width: 200, _width: 200, filter: 'text'},
{'city':'bangalore',title: 'City', field: 'city', width: 200, _width: 200, filter: 'dropdown'},
{'country':'India',title: 'Country', field: 'country', width: 200, _width: 200, filter: 'dropdown'}
}]```

I tried below code
console.log([...Obj,...arr])
````

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you want to merge? Is it based on the value of `field` key in Array element and then adding that key and value from the object to Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const obj = { id: 49, city: 'bangalore', country: 'India' }
const arr = [{title: 'Location ID',field: 'id',width: 200,_width: 200,filter: 'text',},{ title: 'City', field: 'city', width: 200, _width: 200, filter: 'dropdown' },{title: 'Country',field: 'country',width: 200,_width: 200,filter: 'dropdown',},]

const result = arr.map(({ field, ...o }) => ({
  [field]: obj[field],
  ...o
}))

console.log(result)
```